# Change Oracle OpenJDK to Amazon Corretto in WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic

hi i am trying to change my Oracle OpenJDK 8 to Amazon Corretto 8 in Weblogic Server.I am successfully able to change it if i create a new domain in weblogic server . But the problem is i need to create all server configuration again in the new domain (example: Data sources). There is an option in the server admin console where we can add the Java Home, Root Directory,Classpath,Arguments to use when server start . I tried to add the Amazon Corretto JDK path in admin console Java Home . But it's still taking old java home value and starting the server . How i can point to new JDK through admin console of weblogic ?

Comment: If you start your server via a script you have to update the setDomainEnv.sh script to update your JDK.
If you start your server via the node manager with the option startScriptEnabled=False you can change your JDK version in the Remote start configuration tab in the admin console.
Last thing, OpenJDK and Amazon Corretto are not supported by Oracle to run WebLogic Server

Comment: Thanks . It worked . Just curious how you are saying Amazone Corretto not supported by Weblogic server . Because when i started the Weblogic server after changing the JDK , server started successfully and showing that it's pointing to Amazon Corretto .

Comment: This means that if you need any help from the Oracle support team they will ask you to reproduce your issue with a certified JDK,